# JmsOutboundGateway retries to connect to mq -> GatewayReplyListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful (maxAttempts=unlimited)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have question about timeout in JmsOutboundGateway for connection **(org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful)**  - in my case mq connection.
When mq manager is down JmsOutboundGateway tries to connect to mq for some time and then release thread/request.

Where I can set or even check this timeout in JmsOutboundGateway? Is it taken from ConnectionFactory?

Why there is value unlimited for FixedBackOff but request will reach timeout.

Error log:

```
org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful.1007] 
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=4, maxAttempts=unlimited}. 
....reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

----**UPDATE**-------

Full error log:

```
org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure.940  ] - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination '' - trying to recover. Cause: null
org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful.1007  ] - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination '' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'LOCAL' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1415)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful.1007  ] - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination '' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=3, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'LOCAL' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1415)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher logExceptionBeforeFailOver.185  ] - An exception was thrown by 'bean 'jmsOutbound...Gateway'; defined in: 'class path resource [/endpoints/GatewayConfig.class]'; from source: '.endpoints....jmsOutbound...Gateway(org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory,org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$ReplyContainerProperties)'' while handling 'GenericMessage [payload= dummy message, headers={Persistence=0, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@20e63967, Format=MQSTR   , errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@20e63967, Priority=4, messageId=[B@4569ec95, id=016d2bb2-9b03-aad8-2dd1-13cb92e6c42e, uuid=bf90a819-5430-49f8-8dd3-a23eb87e515f, timestamp=1710398153261}]': failed to handle a message in the [bean 'jmsOutboundGateway'; defined in: 'class path resource [.../endpoints/GatewayConfig.class]'; from source: 'com....configuration.endpoints.GatewayConfig.jmsOutbound...Gateway(org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory,org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$ReplyContainerProperties)']; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'LOCAL' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1415)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.. Failing over to the next subscriber.
```

**Code :**

```
    @MessagingGateway(name = "LocalGateway")
    public interface LocalGateway {
    
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
        ListenableFuture<Message<String>> sendMsg(Message<String> request);
    
    }
```

---

```
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputLocalChannel(AsyncTaskExecutor gatewayReqExecutor) {
        return new ExecutorChannel(gatewayReqExecutor);
    }
  
    @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
        public JmsOutboundGateway firstHandler(){
        // some code
    }
    
    @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputLocalChannel")
        public JmsOutboundGateway secondHandler(){
        // some code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior. The `BackOff` is there for a listener container, but `JmsOutboundGateway` is activated by an external call, therefore it is OK that it fails after some timeout. It is not OK to block the requestor infinitely.

You can think about a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` applied for this gateway, but again: it is better to think about some logic to deal with those lost connections in your application instead of trying to wait for a long time.

Comment: But still I don't know what timeout is used for external call on jmsOutboundGateway - that stops infinite loop trying to reconnect to mq server that is turned off. I would like to  change this timeout.  I used RequestHandlerRetryAdvice but still messages was hanging on jmsoutboundgateway more than time declared in retry adivce.

Comment: Yeah... If we talk about that `JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer`, then there is no way exposed property like `recoveryMaxAttempts` as we have for `recoveryInterval`. We will fix that soon enough. For the `but request will reach timeout` we would need that specific exception to analyze.

Comment: I added full error log.  But  one strange thing.   I'm using gateway via method in gateway interface 
        **ListenableFuture<Message<String>> sendMsg(Message<String> request);**  I'm adding callback - and its suspicious that while debug messages that are failing with above error should go to  **onFailure** - but it not happens - flow that goes thru jmsOutboundGateway (where mq server is down) some how utilize request and nothing is triggering callback.  Even I have two gateways attached to one channel and it looks like roundRobin load balancing doesn't work properly.

Comment: So one gateway its working fine and one have problem to connect to mq server - and it almost kill flows - throughput -  extremely slow down and for sure not using round robin or maybe somehow blocks gateway threads ?  and when I start failed mq server  messages from gateway that was failing - all blocked messages are processed successfully - no timeout was reached - but before they where hanging for long time (few minutes) - maybe here -> GatewayReplyListenerContainer  .

Comment: It stucks on  inputLocalChannel( executor channel ). Messages are waiting for processing  before load balancing  - due to one queue manager is down. Gateway processes only 2 messages in a second  - is there any limitation in channel / jmsOutboundGateway

Comment: The `@MessagingGateway` has  a `defaultReplyTimeout` which is `30 seconds` starting with version `6.1`. Before that it was like really forever. This still won't help to unblock that re-connection retry from the `JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer`. As you said before: it looks like that `maxAttempts=unlimited` is a culprit. We can fix it in the next version but for now there is no workaround if you rely on `useReplyContainer = true`.

Comment: But what holds those threads in executor for channel before it reaches JmsOutboundGateway - and what is timeouting those requests  ? reconnect is forever but something stops flow.  It's looks like all threads from executor channel are waiting for connection and they not failing over.  Load balancing did not happen.

Comment: The flow fails from the top level `@MessagingGateway`. It just gives up waiting for reply. That's why no fail over in the channel. All the scheduled tasks in that `ExecutorChannel` are abandoned and they indeed are blocked on that reconnect in the subscriber for this channel.

Comment: But few requests are passed to second  subscriber (with proper connection) - like 2 requests per second. Why load balancing is not working properly at this point - if there is many threads in channel executor half of them should process request (by working subscriber) but this not happens. it's stuck on 2 transactions per second on second subscriber and rest is blocked.

Comment: The rest is blocked because no threads in that executor to process new tasks. Existing threads are busy waiting for connection to come back.

Comment: But why some of request are processed ? and the speed of processing is same (even if I add extra threads to executors for channel and MessagingGateway  )

Comment: looks like **Connection connection = createConnection();** in **JmsOutboundGateway$sendAndReceiveWithoutContainer** could block it while trying to connect or its holding on **DefaultMessageListenerContainer$refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful**. But I can't check it what is directly stopping this flow for so long time.  And which timeout stop process and redirect processing to callback. When I set on gateway replyTimeout it will kill thread and callback won't happen - no onFailure invocations - so I don't  want to set it.

Comment: OK. Can you share some simple project with us to reproduce and play with, please?

Comment: it won't be easy but I will try to create something :)